# Why does 'until' exist?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Is there any reason why the command `until` was implemented into bash/shell (I'm still unsure which)? Is there anything you can't do with a negation on a `while` statement? Is it faster than using the `NOT` CPU function? - unlikely...

Comment: @displayName no, it's that grey zone of open-ended questions that don't quite fit into the site's scope but are believed to be useful by many. Look for highly-voted closed questions with [data.se] and you will find quite a few more. See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167516/how-can-i-encourage-stack-overflow-to-rein-in-the-subjective-vigilantes .

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Indeed, but when I was thinking about where to post it, only 3 places came to mind, StackOverflow, SuperUser and Unix&Linux. I don't think it fits perfectly into any of these - and on StackOverflow, it will get the highest interest because of the community here. But.. those are just my thoughts ;)

Comment: Failed a review because of this one. But this is not revenge downvote. "Is there any reason"-> obvisouly it's for Syntax. "Anything you can't do"-> Until..While just say it out loud and discover the differencies! "Is it faster"-> Have you try ? Any bechmark, data anything? With out speeking about on or off topic. As bonus the 'until' instead of `until` buzz me. If the question was about the way bash execute it( check before or after), I would have understand it.

Comment: @PierreLebon I have no idea what review you are talking about. Anyway, to address your comment, which was more of a opinion than a fact: Something that may seem obvious to you, doesn't have to be to others - including me. How can I know for sure, that it was implemented solely as a syntactic sugar? 
Also.. about that benchmark thing, that was just a side question, or rather, a possible explanation for my question, which I immediately concluded as quite implausible.
Also, you can just ask nicely and will edit that `until` :D I just used the wrong quotes.

Comment: @PierreLebon If I were to ask difference between `if` and `case`, would that make more sense? How would I even know, that case had "fall through" without asking? A question on SO actually taught me, that it is called "fall through", so, yeah, those are my reasons behind this question.

Comment: @PierreLebon if you wish to discuss the review, please do this on meta.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Bash supports it because it conforms to POSIX - specifically, [IEEE Std 1003.1, 2004 Edition - Shell Command Language - The until Loop](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_04_11). The feature predates GNU, and GNU `bash` repo has it [since the 1st commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/diff/parse.y?id=726f63884db0132f01745f1fb4465e6621088ccf) 21 years ago.

[As Guillaume also explains in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43318769/648265), **the rationale behind the feature was (a misguided attempt at) readability.** They tried to micromanage things here because **shell language was initially targeted at end users** rather than professional programmers (like BASIC and SQL).

However, **such redundant syntax** that does exactly the same thing at the same code complexity **proved to be more trouble than it's worth**: by providing two, rather than one, canonical forms for a stock construct, it actually hurt readability rather than improve it and introduced unnecessary decisions to make<sup>1</sup>. That's why it's only present in a few languages designed around that time and likewise intended to be "close to natural language" - like Perl and Visual Basic.

**Nowadays, this approach has evolved into the [syntax sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_sugar) concept**<sup>2</sup>: a redundant construct is only introduced if it significantly simplifies code by replacing an entire boilerplate construct that is used sufficiently often. C# is a good example of this.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>"which one to use here? change it when I change the condition or not? why do I even care?" From my experience, it's the same in Pascal procedures vs functions: I remember having to switch a subroutine between these two multiple times as I design the code. It simply imposes redundant work on the programmer, thus wasting their time.</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>I narrow down the term here because I'm expressing things from a language designer's point of view. It's rather "what is now considered good syntax sugar". Since from a language designer's POV, any other SS effectively doesn't exist.</sub>

Comment: 'That's why it's only present in a few languages designed around that time and likewise intended to be "close to natural language"' plus Ruby, because some people refuse to learn from history ;)

Comment: "nowadays, this approach has evolved into the syntactic sugar concept" doesn't quite jive with the linked Wikipedia article, which correctly states "The term syntactic sugar was coined by Peter J. Landin in **1964**" (emphasis added). By the way, why does C have `while(condition)` when you could just write `for(;condition;)` with the same semantics and number of keystrokes? This redundancy isn't more trouble than its worth?

Comment: @rici by "nowadays... evolved", I mean in general practice (if no one knows of an invention, it effectively doesn't exist). It's the same story with [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). `for(;condition;)` wasn't promoted as a canonical way of doing anything (I can't recall the last time I saw it in code, if ever) and is much inferior (severely less readable and comprehensible) - so the aforementioned problems with a dichotomy do not arise (you can call `while` syntactic sugar here).

Comment: @ivan: I can assure you that when I started coding in the early 70s, the concepts of syntactic sugar and desugaring were already (or still) part of tge core vocabulary in language design.

Comment: @ivan. I'm certainly not advocating the removal of `while` in favour of `for` (or vice versa); simply pointing out that the mere fact that a simple alternative exists is no reason to abandon a useful syntax. You might feel that `until` could be replaced by `while not` without loss, but that's an *opinion* and others may disagree. (I'm neutral on the question.) In the case of `while` and `for`, I'd say that `for` is sugar for a while loop, not the other way around. The shell while loop is interesting in that you can make it into a mid-test or even an end-test, but the sugar could be sweeter...

Comment: @rici the key phrase here is "the aforementioned problems with a dichotomy do not arise". Do they?

Comment: @rici Okay, I was wrong about the syn sugar per se. Was I wrong that duplicate syntax has given way to syn sugar (among other things) as a readability increase tool since the 90s? I.e. does the post need to be fact fixed, or not?

Comment: @ivan: the Google style guide has a section comparing `while (1)` with `for (;;)`. It prefers the latter but many  programmers prefer the former. (I changed my style to conform with G but I might change back now.) I still sometimes go back and forth between `for(;cond;action){}` and `while(cond)action;`. So yes, there's a dichotomy. But the resolution is a matter of aesthetics and consequently *opinion*. It does not (in my opinion :-) ) respond to some absolute Law of Engineering, which is my only point: styles vary over the years, and then change back, and then again. Nothing wrong...

Comment: ... with that as long as you remember that styles, even if they have resonance at a certain moment in time and in a certain community etc., are still styles.

Comment: @ivan, with respect to syntactic sugar, I personally don't think the concept expressed in your answer corresponds to my understanding of the term. Quoting Wikipedia, "syntactic sugar is syntax within a programming language that is designed to make things easier to read or to express". If someone feels that `until (x.is_empty())` is easier to read than `while(!x.is_empty())`, that would qualify (imho). The idea is that you can desugar a language using something like a macro facility or tree rewriter, resulting in a core language that is easier to compiler (because it has less syntax).

Comment: @rici Of course, `until` formally qualifies as SS. But I'm expressing things from a language designer's perspective here. Any SS introduces an inherent problem of needing to choose between the two forms and switch between them as code changes. A well-chosen SS would undermine this problem by making the choice obvious by "clearly winning" and by making the need to switch nigh-nonexistent. Any other SS effectively does not exist for a language designer - so I implicitly narrowed down the term to exclude them.

Comment: @rici The answer boils down to explaining how `until` proved to be a bad choice for SS and how they learned from that in languages designed later.

Answer (score 7):

Everything you can do with `until` can be done with `while`. Your code may be 1 character shorter thanks to this “optimization” and some interpreters *may* be slightly faster but it would be ridiculously insignificant compared to the rest to the code.

As far as I know this statement mostly exists because some languages have it so it’s a bit easier to port from a language to bash. But as of today (2017) I think the overwhelming majority of languages support the `while` statement and very few support `until`. I would recommend using exclusively `while` so that other programmers who read your code won’t waste time asking themselves what `until` does.

Not to mention some languages have a `until` statement which is executed at the end of the loop (instead of the beginning), which would bring a lot of unnecessary confusion.

Answer (score 7):

The reason for such statement is not so much technical (indeed, a inverted `while` would have the same meaning) but semantic.

`until (condition) {do something}`

can be closer to natural language than

`while (not condition) {do something}`

This is especially true when the condition itself is expressed as a negative, as reading multiple negations does not flow as neatly:

`while (not not_connected) {}`
vs
`until (not_connected) {}`.

Comment: This is not the same `until` as in Pascal. In Pascal the difference between `while` and `until` is the time when the condition gets checked. The `while` loop checks the condition before the execution of the body. The `until` loop checks the condition after the execution of the body.

Comment: "_when the condition itself is expressed as a negative_" you should get slapped in the face with a big trout anyway.

Comment: @ceving Now that's confusing, as in C-style languages (and others?) that concept is structured as `do {...} while ();`.

Comment: @CompuChip The slapping would be warranted. A better example would have been `while (not present)` vs `until (present)`.